# calling method on link on coming from menu

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee

how can i call a mehtod on coming from another screen to new one . i want to call method onload of the screen from menu.but it should not call method on load on same screen..
actualy i am calling clear fields methods every time whenever i am coming from another screen but while on same screen if it load by search button it does call clear method.

```xhtml
   <script type="text/javascript"> 
  window.onbeforeunload = function()
  {
     exitFunc();
     alert("test 1");
  }
</script> 

<h:form id="exitForm"> -->
<p:remoteCommand name="exitFunc" actionListener="#{letterCancellationManager.clearMaster}" /> 
</h:form>
<f:metadata>
  <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{letterCancellationManager.clearMaster}"/>
</f:metadata>
```

i have tried this but this is clearing fields every time whenever it loads but i want to clear fields coming from another screen .please reply

Comment: A well-designed jsf view should have the fields cleared when you come into it. Are you using the proper scopes for the managed beans?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have solved this problem with this

clearing cache
manager backing bean:

---

```
private String id; //its setter getters
________________________________________________________________________________

//clear method
public void clearMaster()
{
 try
 {
    if(id!=null && id.equals("1"))
    {
     byRfq="";
     byNsn="";
     byDoc="";
     byLetterNo="";
     byLetterDate=null;
     byEmailDate=null;      
    }
  }catch(Exception ee){}
}
________________________________________________________________________________

//write inside the method which is calling default on master
try{
 int id = Integer.valueOf(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("id"));
 this.id=id+"";      
}catch(Exception ee){}
id="";
________________________________________________________________________________
inside UI JSF VIEW of screen
<f:view >
<f:metadata>
<f:viewParam name="id" value="#{letterCancellationManager.id}" />
<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{letterCancellationManager.clearMaster}"/>     
</f:metadata>
```